# Hadoop -copyFromLocal failing to find file

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to execute -copyFromLocal through oozie shell.

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/usr/test/test1'  '/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/shell/'
```

But it is failing sometimes with error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.TLA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "TLA".
copyFromLocal: `/usr/test/test1': No such file or directory
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Sometimes it is working fine but sometime it is failling to copy. Please help me to short out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does oozie come into picture?

Comment: Hi..I am using CDH4.3. I have a use case in which i need to schedule a job for which i am using oozie. Oozie will run the shell command for copying the file from local to HDFS.

Comment: Are you sure you have the file in the location: /usr/test/test1?

Comment: Yeah it is there.Sometimes it is identifying the location and running successfully but sometimes it is not identifying the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to add comment I will respond to your question assuming you have a Hadoop cluster with at least 2 machines/nodes.
If this is true, your action will be executed on an arbitrary node on cluster, each time. This is why sometimes it finds the file (in case it runs on the machine that has the file, probably the namenode) and sometimes it doesn't find the file (in case the action is executed on a different node).
It will work every time only if you make sure the file exists in the same location on each node in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks cipi, i found the same after many try. But don't you think copying it to all the nodes/machine is an overhead. I am searching for a better approach. If u or anyone have a better way please do suggest.

Comment: Or something i can change so that it will always look for files in one node instead of random nodes.

Comment: With oozie I would implement this copy this way: Put all files to be managed by an ftp server, and in oozie use a java node to copy files from ftp to hadoop. This way it is not important the node that executes the java action. But, depending on the requirements, sometimes it is better to copy files from local filesystem to hdfs as soon as they arrive or on a regular basis using a java program or a script, without oozie.